# Saving an Android Spinner value as Text for use elsewhere

Tags: android, spinner, storage, sharedpreferences, internal

I'm relatively new to Android Applications and have an App up and running and working (almost) how I want.

It's a fairly simple app that has only a couple of buttons/activities with the main goal of showing a Barcode on the screen.

I have it all working with a Custom Font and Hardcoded value to populate the barcode but i'm now looking to expand the app to give the user the option to select the barcode number they require.

I have a settings activity which, at the moment, holds only a spinner and button.  What i'm wanting to do is have the user select the barcode value from the spinner and then click the button to save the value (as Text) so that I can use the value to populate the barcode.

I've done some reading and come across SharedPreferences and Internal Storage but having trouble deciding which one would be best to use.

Will SharedPreferences continue to store the information if the application is closed or would the user need to repopulate the settings again?  Would Internal Storage be a better option for this?

If so, what would be the best way to go about saving the selected value and then populating it within another activity?

Answer (score 1):

Each value you store in `SharedPreferences` will remain until your app is uninstalled. In this case `SharedPreferences` would be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.  I'll be using that then.  As soon as I reach the minimum I'll be sure to vote up your answer!